# Problems when implementing OpenCV TPS ShapeTransformer in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to implement an image warp using the ThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer in OpenCV using Python. I am using a C++ example posted in the OpenCV forum ([link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/69384/shape-transformers-and-interfaces)) but I am encountering various problems due to the differences in the OpenCV Python API.

As in the linked example, I am working with a single image onto which I will define a small number of source points and the corresponding target points. The end result should be a warped copy of the image. The code so far is as follows:

```
tps=cv2.createThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer()

sourceshape= np.array([[200,10],[400,10]],np.int32)
targetshape= np.array([[250,10],[450,30]],np.int32)

matches=list()
matches.append(cv2.DMatch(1,1,0))
matches.append(cv2.DMatch(2,2,0))

tps.estimateTransformation(sourceshape,targetshape,matches)
```

But I am getting an error in the estimateTransformation method:

```
cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.1.0\modules\shape\src\tps_trans.cpp:193: error: (-215) 
(pts1.channels()==2) && (pts1.cols>0) && (pts2.channels()==2) && (pts2.cols>0) in function cv::ThinPlateSplineShapeTransformerImpl::estimateTransformation
```

I can understand that something is incorrect in the data structures that I have passed onto estimateTransformation and I'm guessing it has to do with the channels since the rows and columns seem to be correct but I do not know how I can satisfy the assertion (pts1.channels()==2) since the parameter is an array of points which I am creating and not an array generated from an image load

I'd be grateful for any pointers to a TPS implementation for image transformation with Python or indeed any help on how to resolve this particular issue. I've tried to find the Python documentation for the ThinPlateShapeTransformer class but it has proved impossible - all I've found is the C++ docs and the only thing i have to go on are the results of the help() function - apologies if I am missing something obvious

Comment: Anyone? Anyone at all?

Comment: Have you found the solution. Please share.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Simple reshaping solved that issue. It is late but someone might find it useful. Here are the lines for reshaping `sourceshape` and `targetshape`:

```
sourceshape=sourceshape.reshape(1,-1,2)
targetshape=targetshape.reshape(1,-1,2)
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: 

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == CV_64FC2) in cv::gemmImpl, file C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\matmul.cpp, line 1190`

Comment: I do not know much about the error, but I think it is the type error. Try converting it as np.int32. Or other formats.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to check the number of matching points. In your code, there are only two matching points, it is difficult to interpolate. May be you can increase up to four matching points, than it will work.

```
sourceshape= np.array([[200,10],[400,10]],np.int32)//increase more point here
targetshape= np.array([[250,10],[450,30]],np.int32)//increase more point here

matches=list()
matches.append(cv2.DMatch(1,1,0))
matches.append(cv2.DMatch(2,2,0))
//add more matches here.
```